# Getting all zero when vectorizing my text dataset after stemming using CountVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing data cleaning and preprocessing on text data.
after tokenization and it's necessary steps I am now trying to generate a matrix from the data with sklearn `CountVectorizer` but when I run the code it prints out only zeros

This is the actual text am working with after I stemmed it.

```
# Stemming
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

ps = PorterStemmer()

stemmed_words=[]
for w in filtered_sent:
    stemmed_words.append(ps.stem(w))

print("Filtered Sentence:",filtered_sent[0:50])
print("Stemmed Sentence:",stemmed_words[0:50])
```

this is the output of the text `stemmed_words`

```
print("Stemmed Sentence:",stemmed_words[0:50])
```

```
Stemmed Sentence: ['0', 'crack', 'adam', 'disco', 'cooki', 'ecstasi', 'discard', 'travel', '...', '1', 'o.k', '.', 'o.k', '.', 'o.k', '.', 'o.k', '.', 'lar', 'play', 'joke', 'joke', 'joke', 'jo', '...', '2', 'free', 'peopl', 'introduct', 'record', 'entranc', 'entra', '...', '3', 'brawl', 'caus', 'doctor', 'osteopathi', 'unreal', '...', '4', 'nobelium', 'nobelium', 'brawl', 'act', 'doctor', 'osteop', '...', '5', 'freemsg']
```

This is the code for the matrix generation

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer

cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2, 2))
text_counts = cv.fit_transform(stemmed_words)
print(text_counts[0:10].toarray())
```

this is my output

```
print(text_counts[0:10].toarray())
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I want to know why i am getting only zeros and no mixed values. thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you also share few lines of the text ?

Comment: also, the `ngram_range=(2, 2)` should be `ngram_range=(1, 2)` ?

Comment: I'm going to edit the post title so that it more accurately represents the actual question. For now, I'm voting to close this, since the code provided is incomplete and there is no data. See: [mcve].

Comment: Could you try replacing the array of words with array of sentences. ie, `stemmed_words = ["0 crack adam disco cooki ecstasi discard", "another sentence"]`

Comment: that will be difficult because that is like the process of the data cleaning, the document is in sentences but on the process of preprocessing it will be broken into list of words.

Comment: What if you use the `char` analyzer?  I got a few 1s after trying that out instead of `word`.

Comment: Actually I think it is working fine, it is just that the matrix is too big. You can see this by printing the entire 1st row or by only count vectorise maybe 5 words. 
`text_counts = cv.fit_transform(stemmed_words[:5])`

Comment: still not working @MarkMoretto is just the same thing.

Comment: @codeblooded this is the error i got.
`raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only" 

ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words`

Comment: @Sabali Change `ngram_range=(1,2)`, also you really should be passing sentence not words that  is why you are getting the above error.

Comment: @codeblooded i have done so the first time you mentioned it, but is not working.

Comment: see usage examples here, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed the untokenized sentences to `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer` otherwise it understand each word as a separate sentence. Hence there is only zeros because it cannot find bi-grams in your input.

Simpler approach would be changing the `build_analyzer` method of the vectorizer (after `self.analyzer == 'word':`), so that you don't have to do it separately.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import pandas as pd

ps = PorterStemmer()

class CustomVectorizer(CountVectorizer): 

    # overwrite the build_analyzer method, allowing one to
    # create a custom analyzer for the vectorizer
    def build_analyzer(self):
        """Return a callable that handles preprocessing and tokenization"""
        if callable(self.analyzer):
            return self.analyzer

        preprocess = self.build_preprocessor()

        if self.analyzer == 'char':
            return lambda doc: self._char_ngrams(preprocess(self.decode(doc)))

        elif self.analyzer == 'char_wb':
            return lambda doc: self._char_wb_ngrams(
                preprocess(self.decode(doc)))

        elif self.analyzer == 'word':


            tokenize = self.build_tokenizer()

            lemmatize = lambda doc: \
                    [ps.stem(token) for token in doc]

            stop_words = self.get_stop_words()

            return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
                lemmatize(tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc)))),
                stop_words)


        else:
            raise ValueError('%s is not a valid tokenization scheme/analyzer' %
                             self.analyzer)

sentences= [" crack adam disco cooki ecstasi discard another sentence", "another sentences"]

vec = CustomVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2, 2))
text_counts = vec.fit_transform(sentences)    
print(pd.DataFrame(text_counts.toarray(),columns=vec.get_feature_names()))
```

```
   adam disco  anoth sentenc  cooki ecstasi  crack adam  discard anoth  disco cooki  ecstasi discard
0           1              1              1           1              1            1                1
1           0              1              0           0              0            0                0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i did as u asked and i even copied your code but i was still getting zeros everywhere

Comment: can you try again with a new kernel because I am getting the posted output.

Comment: Sorry. I could find the reason then.